# Importing custom font to a separate Styles.js file

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to import a custom font to a style-specific Styles.js file.
The font is currently imported to the main App.js file but somehow I can't use it in Styles.js.

The code I'm using in App.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Gamefrom "./components/Game.js";
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export let customFonts = {
  'headline': require('../assets/fonts/MonotypeCorsivaRegular.ttf'),
};


export class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    fontsLoaded: false,
  };

  async _loadFontsAsync() {
    await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
    this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.fontsLoaded) {
      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <Game/>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }  else {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
  }
};

export default App;
```

My code inside Styles.js:

```js
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headline: {
      fontSize: 35,
      color: "black",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontFamily: "headline"
    },
})
```

Comment: load all the fonts once in your app.js and use them separately in different  styles.js

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the way you have imported your custom font and the way you have implemented `App.js`.

Please try as below.

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Gamefrom "./components/Game.js";
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fontsLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  async _loadFontsAsync() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'headline': require('../assets/fonts/MonotypeCorsivaRegular.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.fontsLoaded) {
      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <Game/>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    else {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
  }
};
```

`Style.js` does not need any changes.

Comment: Thank you, I still can't get the style apply to other component files but I'll post the solution once I have it